# How to troubleshoot the dimensions for my layers in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dimensions, conv-neural-network, one-class-classification

I am working through my training loop errors where my dimensions are incorrect. Of course there is other code here and there, but I thought this the most important to show here. I feel everywhere I look online I am getting told different info or in different ways that I don't know how to get at least the first layer correct so I can troubleshoot from there.  I know what goes out of one layer goes into the next layer, those dimensions must match.  Looking at this link https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-layer-dimensions-what-sizes-should-they-be-and-why-4265a41e01fd

I think the first layer should be `nn.Conv2d([batch_size, channels, height, width])` 
or  `nn.Conv2d([62,3,800,600])`.  This, however, gives an error thinking 
`RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 3 62 800 600, expected input[62, 3, 800, 600] to have 62 channels, but got 3 channels instead`.  So, I think it is expecting the channels to be the first number, the number of features, then (H, W).  So need to do switch #s around.......
However, get error

```
in _max_pool2d
    input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
RuntimeError: Given input size: (62x1x1). Calculated output size: (62x0x0). Output size is too small
```

How can I understand these needed dimensions?

Image info:

```
Dimensions = 1920x1080 (W x H)
Bit depth 24
```

Code:

```
---------------------Hyper Parameters-------------------------------------------
SIZE TRAINING SET = 320
SIZE TEST SET = 80

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR = 1e-1
N_EPOCHS = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 62
DROPOUT = 0.25

transformations = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((800,600),interpolation=Image.BICUBIC),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=10,saturation=10,contrast=30,hue=0.1),
    #transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor()])

#  -------------------------------------- CNN Class ----------------------------------------------
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 7, (3, 3))
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(7, 14, (3, 3))
        self.convnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(14)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(14, 28, (3, 3))

        self.conv4= nn.Conv2d(28, 56, (3, 3))
        self.convnorm4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(56)
        self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))

        self.conv5= nn.Conv2d(56, 112, (3, 3))
        self.convnorm5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(112)
        self.pool5 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))

        self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(112, 224, (2, 2))
        self.convnorm6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(224)
        self.pool6 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))


        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(87584, 100)
        self.linear1_bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(100)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(DROPOUT)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(100, 7)
        self.act = torch.relu

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool1(self.act(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool2(self.convnorm2(self.act(self.conv2(x))))
        x = self.act(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.pool4(self.convnorm4(self.act(self.conv4(x))))
        x = self.pool5(self.convnorm5(self.act(self.conv5(x))))
        x = self.pool6(self.convnorm6(self.act(self.conv6(x))))
        x = self.drop((self.linear1_bn(self.act(self.linear1(x.view(len(x), -1))))))
        return self.linear2(x)


# -------------------------------------- Training Prep --------------------------------------------------
model = CNN().to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LR)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

# -------------------------------------- Training Loop -----------------------------------------------
print("Starting training loop...")
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    model.train()
    loss_train = 0
    for iter, traindata in enumerate(train_loader):
        train_inputs, train_labels = traindata
        train_inputs, train_labels = train_inputs.to(device), train_labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        logits = model(train_inputs)
        loss = criterion(logits, train_labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        loss_train += loss.item()
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), "cnnmodel.pt")
        print('Batch {} and Loss {:.5f}'.format(iter,loss_train/BATCH_SIZE))
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load("cnnmodel.pt"))
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for iter, valdata in enumerate(val_loader, 0):
            val_inputs, val_labels = valdata
            val_inputs1, val_labels1 = val_inputs.to(device), val_labels.to(device)
            y_test_pred = model(val_inputs1)
            tar_=val_labels.cpu().numpy()
            loss = criterion(y_test_pred, val_labels1)
            loss_test = loss.item()
            print('Validation Loss {:.5f}'.format(loss_test))
            validation_output=np.where(y_test_pred.cpu().numpy()>0.5,1,0)


    print("Epoch {} | Train Loss {:.5f}".format( epoch, loss_train/BATCH_SIZE))

            return self.linear2(x)
```

Error message:

```
Starting training loop...
Expected: %s to exist.
NoneType: None
Expected: %s to exist.
NoneType: None
Expected: %s to exist.
NoneType: None
Expected: %s to exist.
NoneType: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Deep-Learning/FinalProject/train_finalproject.py", line 310, in <module>
    logits = model(train_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Deep-Learning/FinalProject/train_finalproject.py", line 287, in forward
    x = self.pool2(self.convnorm2(self.act(self.conv2(x))))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 345, in forward
    return self.conv2d_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 342, in conv2d_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 14 7 3 3, expected input[62, 2, 399, 299] to have 7 channels, but got 2 channels instead
```

Comment: The CNN you posted does not seem to be the one that produces the errors. At least running this CNN with an input of dimension `[62, 3, 800, 600]` works as expected. The errors are the results from completely different configurations, for the first error you must have had `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(62, 3, (3, 3))`  and for the last one `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 2, (3, 3))`. The current version is correct, make sure you're using this exact same version.